# React Js - Material UI - Change Min Date as per previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 date pickers in material UI-

```
From Date -

<KeyboardDatePicker
 value={initialDateFrom}
 disableFuture={true}
onChange={handleFromDateChange}
>
</KeyboardDatePicker>

To Date -

<KeyboardDatePicker
 value={initialDateTo}
 disableFuture={true}
onChange={handleToDateChange}
>
</KeyboardDatePicker>

const [initialDateFrom , setInitialDateFrom]= useState<any>(null);
const [initialDateTo , setInitialDateTo]= useState<any>(null);

const handleFromDateChange =(event:any , value :any)=>{
  setInitialDateFrom(value)
}

const handleToDateChange =(event:any , value :any)=>{
  setInitialDateTo(value)
}
```

What I am trying to achieve -

If I select  11-Oct-2021 as From date , I want to disable all the previous dates in To Date date picker to 11-Oct-2021. To Date - Date picker should show only future dates from 11-Oct-2021.

What I tried -

`minDate = {initialDateFrom}` in `To Date` datepicker

`value.minDate = initialDateFrom` in `handleFromDateChange`

But this did not helped.

Comment: have you tried minDate={new Date(initialDateFrom)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach, I have created one more state to handle minDate

```
const [initialDateFrom , setInitialDateFrom]= useState<any>(null);
const [minDate, setMinDate] = useState<any>(null);
const [initialDateTo , setInitialDateTo]= useState<any>(new Date());

const handleFromDateChange =(event:any , value :any)=>{
  setInitialDateFrom(new Date(value));
  setMinDate(new Date(value))
}

const handleToDateChange =(event:any , value :any)=>{
  setInitialDateTo(value)
}

<KeyboardDatePicker
 value={initialDateFrom}
 disableFuture={true}
 onChange={handleFromDateChange}
>
</KeyboardDatePicker>

<KeyboardDatePicker
 value={initialDateTo}
 minDate={minDate}
 onChange={handleToDateChange}
>
</KeyboardDatePicker>
```